# AssertionError in generalized_box_iou

Tags: python, transformer-model

I'm following a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkhXoj_Vvr4) to form a DETR model for face detection using same dataset and code. If I get it right, I'm planning to modify it for my project. Right now, I'm getting an AssertionError when I run main.py. The output looked like this:

```
File "F:\DETR\util\box_ops.py", line 51, in generalized_box_iou
    assert (boxes1[:, 2:] >= boxes1[:, :2]).all()

AssertionError
```

I tried using pdb:

```
import pdb
def generalized_box_iou(boxes1, boxes2):
    """
    Generalized IoU from https://giou.stanford.edu/

    The boxes should be in [x0, y0, x1, y1] format

    Returns a [N, M] pairwise matrix, where N = len(boxes1)
    and M = len(boxes2)
    """
    # degenerate boxes gives inf / nan results
    # so do an early check
    pdb.set_trace()
    assert (boxes1[:, 2:] >= boxes1[:, :2]).all()
    assert (boxes2[:, 2:] >= boxes2[:, :2]).all()
    iou, union = box_iou(boxes1, boxes2)

    lt = torch.min(boxes1[:, None, :2], boxes2[:, :2])
    rb = torch.max(boxes1[:, None, 2:], boxes2[:, 2:])

    wh = (rb - lt).clamp(min=0)  # [N,M,2]
    area = wh[:, :, 0] * wh[:, :, 1]

    return iou - (area - union) / area
```

I got following output:

```
> f:\detr\util\box_ops.py(53)generalized_box_iou()
     51     # so do an early check
     52     pdb.set_trace()
---> 53     assert (boxes1[:, 2:] >= boxes1[:, :2]).all()
     54     assert (boxes2[:, 2:] >= boxes2[:, :2]).all()
     55     iou, union = box_iou(boxes1, boxes2)


p boxes1[:, 2:]
tensor([[0.4649, 0.6003],
        [0.7213, 0.9160],
        [0.6872, 0.9912],
        [0.5093, 0.9677],
        [0.2026, 0.9832],
        [0.6015, 0.9870],
        [0.5790, 0.9843],
        [0.5445, 0.9818],
        [0.1135, 0.9933],
        [0.5385, 1.0058],
        [0.3093, 0.5704],
        [0.6826, 0.7190],
        [0.6489, 0.9788],
        [0.5300, 0.8577],
        [0.3642, 0.9970],
        [0.6232, 0.9240],
        [0.6089, 0.9871],
        [0.6521, 0.9505],
        [0.1352, 1.0018],
        [0.5606, 0.9524]], device='cuda:0')

p boxes1[:, :2]
tensor([[0.2439, 0.1090],
        [0.6295, 0.3856],
        [0.4519, 0.0084],
        [0.3994, 0.5895],
        [0.1331, 0.4344],
        [0.4986, 0.5543],
        [0.4745, 0.5840],
        [0.1148, 0.0825],
        [0.0351, 0.5683],
        [0.3938, 0.1501],
        [0.1885, 0.1104],
        [0.6015, 0.3602],
        [0.4971, 0.0174],
        [0.4392, 0.5872],
        [0.1143, 0.1519],
        [0.5410, 0.4566],
        [0.4996, 0.5593],
        [0.0434, 0.1141],
        [0.0593, 0.3776],
        [0.4481, 0.0401]], device='cuda:0')

p boxes2[:, 2:]
tensor([[0.5703, 0.3911],
        [0.5566, 0.4319]], device='cuda:0')

p boxes2[:, :2]
tensor([[0.5361, 0.3342],
        [0.3488, 0.0721]], device='cuda:0')
```

I get different values for boxes1. One time it was p boxes1[:, 2:]

```
tensor([[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]], device='cuda:0')
```

The value keeps on changing. I have used the same train and val json files and images from the tutorial.

Comment: It means that the `generalized_box_iou` function is used incorrectly. What exactly is your question about it?

Comment: Why am I getting the AssertionError? The code runs fine in the tutorial.

Comment: Because the condition `(boxes1[:, 2:] >= boxes1[:, :2]).all()` on the input data `boxes1` is not fulfilled.

Comment: I know that. But what could have gone wrong if I'm using same code, same dataset (images) and train and val json files like that in the tutorial?